# Run Powershell with lower version

Tags: powershell

How can i test a powershell script with powershell.exe version 1?
There is a version parameter but it doesn't work as expected:

```
C:\Users\skampmann>powershell -version 1 -command "$psversiontable.psversion.major"
2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the `-version` parameter only works for the value `2.0` or just `2` but not for `1` or `3`.

To test your scripts in PowerShell 1 you have to find a machine which still has that. Just set up a VM with an old OS.

Comment: `4` also does not work. With PS v5 it run v5 not v4.

Comment: @PetSerAl - Yeah, I think the parameter is only for 2, `Windows PowerShell Version 2.0 Engine` is a separate Windows feature. If you remove that `-version` should not work at all.

Comment: `powershell -version 3 get-clipboard` works, although Get-Clipboard seems to be a new cmdlet in PowerShell 5.0

Comment: I got it. It's because `powershell -version 3 -command "$psversiontable.psversion.major"` prints 5